# Dragula - Drag elements from multiple container to destination container

Tags: javascript, dragula

I have got 4 containers, where first 3 are the source containers and the elements are to be added in the 4th container(destination container). The elements from the source containers shouldn't allow to drop the elements to the  neighboring containers expect for the destination containers and the elements dropped in the destination containers can dropped back to its respective containers.

here's my code

```js
dragula([document.getElementById('col1'),document.getElementById('col2'),document.getElementById('col3'), document.getElementById('done')],{
accepts: function (el, target, source, sibling) {
    return target == document.getElementById('done') ;
});
```

```css
.wrapper{    display: table;}
.container {
  border: 2px dotted #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-left: 20px;
   position:relative;
    text-align:center
}

.container div {
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: move;
}
.vl:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
   border-left: 6px solid green;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="col1" class="container">
    <div>Mango 1</div>
    <div>Mango 2</div>
    <div>Mango 3</div>
  </div>
    <div id="col2" class="container">
    <div>Guava 1</div>
    <div>Guava 2</div>
    <div>Guava 3</div>
  </div>
    <div id="col3" class="container">
    <div>Peach 1</div>
    <div>Peach 2</div>
    <div>Peach 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="done" class="container vl">
    
  </div>
</div>
```